# Dynamic text change from particles

Tags: javascript, text, particles

How to dynamically change the text to another, without rebooting, that is, a dynamic change in the arrangement of particles

```
Partallan.init("PARTALLAN");
```

example: http://codepen.io/lateek35/pen/QbZdEB

Comment: You should show your work here, preferably in a code snippet, and help us understand what problems/issues you are having. If you haven't already, read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment section, you should tell us what you already try, and what did not work.

Anyway, here I'll explain you how I would have done it.

As you can see, each particle's object has a property `ox` and `oy` which correspond to the original anchor coordinate of the particle.

I think the step to follow is to:

1 - Re-use the `writeText` method to create a new text in an offcanvas and save the new coordinates.

2 - Tween the values `ox` and `oy` of each particles in the `particles` array to the new coordinates you retrieved in the previous step

The tricky point here is the number of particles already existing. It's all depend on the new text used, but I think it's impossible that you get the same amount of coordinate than the number of particles. So you will have to either add new particle in you array or delete some (and of course implement an animation for this, probably with a method like `particle.die()`)

Hope it will help you